# REST API uses asynchronous (events) internally

Tags: events, architecture

I am implementing a REST API that internally places a message on a message queue and receives a message as a response on a different topic.

- How could API implementation handle publishing and consuming different messages and responds to the client?
- What if it never receives a message?
- How does the service handle this time-out scenario?

#### Example

I am implementing a REST API to process an order. The implementation internally publishes a series of messages to verify the payment, update inventory, and prepare shipping info. Finally, it sends the response back to the client.

Answer (score 0):

Queues are too low-level abstraction to implement your requirements directly. Look at an orchestration solution like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) that makes programming such async systems trivial.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of the Temporal open source project.

Answer (score 0):

> How could API implementation handle publishing and consuming different messages and responds to the client?

Even though messaging systems can be used in RPC like fashion:

- there is a request topic/queue and a reply topic/queue
- with a request identifier in the messages' header/metadata

this type of communication kills the promise of the messaging system: *decouple components in time and space*.

Back to your example. If ServiceA receives the request then it publishes a message to topicA and returns with an [202 Accepted status code](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-202-accepted/) to indicate that the **request is received but not yet processed** completely. In the response you can indicate an url on which the consumer of ServiceA's API can retrieve the latest status of its previously issued request.

> What if it never receives a message?

In that case the request related data remains in the same state as it was at the time of the message publishing.

> How does the service handle this time-out scenario?

You can create scheduled jobs to clean-up never finished/got stuck requests. Based on your business requirements you can simple delete them or transfer them to manual processing by the customer service.

---

#### Order placement use case

Rather than creating a customer-facing service which waits for all the processing to be done you can define several statuses/stages of the process:

- Order requested
- Payment verified
- Items locked in inventory
- ...
- Order placed

You can inform your customers about these status/stage changes via websocket, push notification, e-mail, etc.. The orchestration of this order placement flow can be achieved for example via the [Saga pattern](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).